# getting request data from getInitialProps()

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, next.js

I am trying to post data from a python script to a Next js server.

```
#python script
import requests 
post_data = {'username':'bob', 'id' : 32}
# POST some form-encoded data:
post_response = requests.post(url='http://localhost:3000/foo', data=post_data)
```

I do get a request on a server, but I do not know how to retrieve the data in getInitalProps(). I have looked at the documentation but there seems to be no such information.

```
 static async getInitialProps({props, req})
     {
        console.log('request data: ', req.data);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Crashed into the very same problem and found the solution well hidden in the [Next.JS forums](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7074#issuecomment-533240644).

In short, first you need the [Urlencoded Body Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlencoded-body-parser) library to help parse the HTTP request object. Using `npm` to install it:

```
npm install --save urlencoded-body-parser
```

Then in your code file, you call its function to get an object with the post variables in it:

```
import parse from 'urlencoded-body-parser';

static async getInitialProps(context)
{
    if (context.req.method === "POST") {
        const data = await parse(context.req);
        console.log("request data: ", data);
    }
}
```

Results, based on question sample data:

```
{
    "username": "bob",
    "id" : "32"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```js
static getInitialProps ({ query: { data } }) {
   console.log('request data: ', data);
}
```

please not that you also need to pass the data in **server.js**:

```js
server.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/pageFoo', req.query)
})
```